# Chrome won't work and won't let me uninstall it

Tags: uninstall, google-chrome, chromium

At one point I was using Chrome and then one day it just stopped working.  All of a sudden it would open but the "Oh Snap" warning would come up.  It doesn't matter what I do, it only shows the "Oh Snap" page.
I wanted to uninstall Chrome and then re-install it but as much as it shows up in Dash Home as installed, it does not show up in the Software Center so I can un-install it.
I did find the Chrome folder (filesystem/opt/google) but even when I try to trash it (shift+delete) it does nothing and I can't delete it.

Is there a way to get rid of it (cleanly) so I can attempt to re-install it?
If I attempt to install a new version of Chrome does it overwrite the old one?
(and how do I do that since it's not showing up on USC?)
Is there a kind of compatibility issue having both browsers installed?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from an USB on a HP Pavillion Laptop.

**S1**
[image: Removing Chromium Terminal]

**S2**
[image: New Search After S1]

**S3**
[image: Chromium Install Attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall it, open a Terminal with alt+t or by searching for "Terminal" in Finder. Then run:

`sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable`

and enter your password when prompted.

You'll need to add Chrome to your repo sources. Run the following in the terminal:

- Add Chrome to your sources list:

`echo deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable non-free main >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

- Add Google's public key:

`sudo wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -`

- Update your sources:

`sudo apt-get update`

You now can then reinstall it with:

`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

Comment: Thanks!  I uninstalled it but have decided not to bother re-installing Chrome.

Comment: No worries, I hope the response helped. Chrome is a good browser (I use it myself). Not that I'm advising against Firefox or anything, it's also very nice.

Comment: Yeah, I liked Chrome but don't like Google being intrusive and spying on me. Chrome seemed slower than Chromium too.  
I like Firefox but it's a pig on the CPU and memory.
Cheers!  
BTW, how do you make a question read as "answered"?

Comment: @dfarrell07NOW my Chromium is acting up, doing EXACTLY the same thing that Chrome was doing; the nasty "AW SNAP" error message and tabs crashing!  Odd that it never did this before until I uninstalled "CHROME"!  Ok, I now have to uninstall "Chromium" so can I use the same terminal verbage and just substitute Chromium for Chrome?  
If I do this I'll re-install Chrome after all.  
Also,PURGE is supposed to get rid of all the files REMOVE leaves behind.  Do you recommend PURGE or REMOVE?  If remove, then how can I get rid of the other files manually since they are usually hidden.

Comment: @Buskieboy To your first post: accept one of the answers to your question.

To your second: Chromium is in the default repos, so you can just use `sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser` and `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: @Buskieboy Regarding purge vs remove, I think for your situation perge would be more appropriate, as you're reinstalling to fix crashes and it seems more logical to also remove configuration files, not just binaries. More information [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=790141).

Comment: As you can see about S1 S2 and S3 show what happened.

**S1** is removing Chromium: Seems OK.

**S2** is new search after removing Chromium: Still approx.46MB of Chromium left behind, with locks!

**S3** is my attempt at reinstalling Chromium with 404 errors etc.

Am I doing some kind of noobie thing wrong?  
Should I install from the Software Center or Chromium's own site?
What's it called a PPA?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the terminal to uninstall chrome ?

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and type

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

I don't think you should have problems with this. After that I always like to purge.

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

To reinstall, download the DEB from Google Chrome website and install from the terminal.

```
sudo dpkg -i ./Downloads/google-chrome.deb
```

Change "./Downloads/" to where you saved the DEB file and "google-chrome.deb" with the real name of the file.

That should do it. Give it a try and let us know if it worked.

Comment: How does updating work with this method? I remember something about Chrome doing silent updates, which should be okay using this method, but what about apt-get updates? I think I've seen Chrome updates with apt. How would the user get those without having Chrome in their sources? Or are silent updates all that are necessary?